# Navigation bar does not work on google chrome

Tags: html, css

I am making a webpage but when testing it using google chrome, the navigation bar for the home page does not work but the navigation bar for all the other pages do work, I have no idea as to why that is. The html is pasted below, please identify any errors which make the code incompatible with google chrome

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li style="float: left"><a href="afterhoursHome.html">AfterHours</a></li>
        <li><a href ="afterhoursContact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href ="afterhoursAbout us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href ="afterhoursGallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href ="afterhoursDelivery.html">Delivery</a></li>
        <li><a>Menu</a></li>
    </ul>

<video width="100%" autoplay loop>
    <source src="afterhoursnew2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

below is the css

```
body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: skyblue;}

    ul {
        margin:0;
        position:fixed;
        list-style-type: none;
        font-size: 27px;    
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color:rgba (71,71,71,0.8)! !important;
        }

    li {
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
        font: "freestyle script"} 

    li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align:center;
        padding: 14px 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: "freestyle script";
        font-weight: bold;}

    li a:hover {
        border-top: 6px solid deeppink;
        color: deeppink;}
```

Comment: what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: The links on the navigation bar. When hovered they do not highlight pink and when clicked nothing happens. However on internet explorer both these functions work

Comment: Try to add html5 skeleton tag, e.g. doc type, head, body

Comment: This solution did not work, however looking into it introduced me to new meta tags which I did not know about before. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**you can try this**

Comment: That solution shows how I started, however when I add all the functions that I would like, the links on the navigation bar stop working. I think its something to do with compatibility of the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

z-index:2;

to css code:

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 27px;    
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:rgba (71,71,71,0.8)! !important;
    z-index:2;
    }
```